# Scoping Issues With GLFW

Tags: c++, scope, glfw

I'm writing a library that wraps around GLFW, among a few other libraries. I have a class that needs to be aware of user interface events, but GLFW uses a callback system where I have to specify a function that GLFW will automatically call when an event happens. This causes issues, because those functions that I have to supply GLFW have no way of being associated with an object of my class, so far as I can tell. For instance:

```
class MyClass {
    MyClass() {
        // Initialize GLFW
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyboardEventFunction);
    }
    // other content
}

void keyboardEventFunction(GLFWwindow *window, int b, int a, int m) {
     // I want to notify the MyClass object, but it's out of scope
}
```

I am aware that GLFW has some non-callback functions to retrieve input data, but if I use those, there's no guarantee that I won't miss something simply because my program didn't happen to check at the exact moment a user provides input. I also lose the ability to check window focus and cursor enter-exit events. How can I get around this issue?

Comment: Hint: global instance of `MyClass`. (yes, it's ugly - its unfortunately the way the library is intended to be used, in my understanding)

Comment: I was hoping there would be a better way than to introduce global variables, but what are you gunna do. To solve a similar problem in the past, I had a global map variable that accepted a pointer to a GLFWwindow object and returned a pointer to the corresponding MyClass object

Comment: You can use `glfwSetWindowUserPointer` to set a (void) pointer to a `MyClass` object. You might need to use some `extern "C"` callback functions that use `glfwGetWindowUserPointer` for method dispatch.